# How to fix problem with intents on google action console

Tags: firebase, dialogflow-es, actions-on-google, dialogflow-es-fulfillment, google-developers-console

I have a problem adding new custom intent in the google console actions in the develop tab.
I have no idea what I'm doing wrong so any help will be so much appreciated. I have projects on google actions console, firebase, and Dialogflow. I'm using integrate with another project by webhook URL endpoint from Dialogflow to GCP but on the first project that intents doesn't work too. I created that second test project to test this problem but I have no clue what I'm doing wrong and update handling errors doesn't help.

There is a ss below [image]

Comment: Is your project supposed to be on Dialogflow or Actions Builder?

Comment: I think it supposed to be on Dialogflow because I have all intents on this but I need to create global intent to make another starting path

Comment: Could you state the steps you were undertaking when this error popped up?

Comment: So I don't why but this is working now. I can add custom intents to and this error doesn't show up. But if I want to make custom intent as global intent I have a problem with the intent name with an error: Invalid intent name '193682f3-dd15-42d4-af61-66b40f18f6eb'. My steps are like I said, I have an app on Dialogflow where I have intents, firebase where I use functions, and google actions console where I test my app. I change intents in my nodejs code, deploy with firebase deploy --only functions. If I change some intent I use the integrations option on Dialogflow.